# Quarkus: Datasource '<default>': FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, quarkus

I wrote a Quarkus JPA/Hibernate app with PostgreSQL DB perfectly working with a JVM - run by 'quarkusDev' gradle task.

When I compile the native application with

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export QUARKUS_PROFILE=****
export PG_USERNAME=*****
export PG_PASSWORD=*****
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
./gradlew build -Dquarkus.package.type=native
```

the compilation goes fine, but when I run the native image I get:

```
14:41:23 WARN  [io.ag.pool] Datasource '<default>': FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "***.***.***.***", user "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", database "*****", SSL on
14:41:23 WARN  [or.hi.en.jd.sp.SqlExceptionHelper] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 28000
14:41:23 ERROR [or.hi.en.jd.sp.SqlExceptionHelper] FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "***.***.***.***", user "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", database "*****", SSL on
14:41:23 ERROR [io.qu.application] Failed to start application: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

I tried to add a pg_hba.conf file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

and put it to

```
/src/main/resources
```

and/or to the native image directory, but without luck.

Also, I configured the resources for my native image adding a 'resources-config.json' to '/src/main/resources':

```
{
  "resources": [
    {
      "pattern": ".*\\.yaml$"
    },
    {
      "pattern": ".*\\.conf$"
    },
    {
      "pattern": ".*\\.txt$"
    },
    {
      "pattern": ".*\\.html$"
    }
  ]
}
```

I added the following line to 'application.yml'

```
quarkus:
  native:
    additional-build-args: -H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=resources-config.json
```

But even doing so, the pga_hba.conf is not found, and when run, the native image keeps on complaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I missed to pass environment variables to the executable.

Of course - obvious after realizing what the problem was! - you not only need to pass DB Environment Variables when you compile the native image - so the tests can be run - but you also need to pass them when you launch it.

So, a script like this solves the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export PG_USERNAME=*****
export PG_PASSWORD=*****
./build/my-native-image.runner
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the pg_hba.conf being used by the Postgres server. You need to find it and add an entry that will match the connection parameters you are sending to the server.

Comment: The PostgreSQL server is on the cloud

Comment: But there is where the error is coming from. So either the pg_hba.conf for the cloud server needs to be changed or the connection parameters you are using need to be changed to ones allowed by the server.  You can't override pg_hba.conf from the client end for the obvious reason.

Comment: Not sure, but I would start by looking at the unmasked version of this " FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "***.***.***.***", user "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", database "*****", SSL on" and see if it is the same as the JVM version. In particular are you using SSL in the JVM?

Comment: Yes, they are the same. There is a single point in the code in which the DB coordinates, including host, user and password, are declared. The logs indicate that these coordinates are correctly understood by both the JVM and native version.

Comment: What logs, the applications or Postgres? This "FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host ..." says the server is not accepting those parameters.  That is your starting point, now you have to work back to why?